# return variable from if statement

Tags: php, ajax

I have a form and inside the form, there's image upload linked with imgur API,
And there's other fields like name, email, etc.
My issue is in the ajax file was the image uploaded and return a link from imgur using API. and stored in a variable and then inserted in my database.

**the variable: $url work in the first if statment and changed from "myurl" to the link that i got from my imgur API and inserted Successfully But in the second if statement, the $url is "myurl" without any changes so how can I update my $url after the first if statement is executed**

```
 <?
    $url = 'myurl';
    

    
    
    if(isset($_FILES['file'])){
    

        $img=$_FILES['file'];
        $allowedTypes = array(IMAGETYPE_PNG, IMAGETYPE_JPEG);
        $detectedType = exif_imagetype($img['tmp_name']);
        if($img['name']=='' or !in_array($detectedType, $allowedTypes)){
            returnJSON(array('tp' => 'error', 't' => 'خطأ', 'm' => 'بجب أن يكون الملف صورة من صيغة PNG أو JPEG','b' => true));
        }else{
            $conn=$database->openConnection();
    
                 $filename = $img['tmp_name'];
                 $client_id="***********";//Your Client ID here
                 $handle = fopen($filename, "r");
                 $data = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
                 $pvars   = array('image' => base64_encode($data));
                 $timeout = 30;
                 $curl    = curl_init();
                 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.imgur.com/3/image.json');
                 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $timeout);
                 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: Client-ID ' . $client_id));
                 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
                 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
                 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $pvars);
                 $out = curl_exec($curl);
                 curl_close ($curl);
                 $pms = json_decode($out,true);
                 $url=$pms['data']['link'];
                 if($url!="myurl"){
                    // just to test if the link is good 
                    $a=$conn->query("INSERT INTO img SET img='".$url."'");
                    if($a->rowCount() > 0){
                        returnJSON(array('tp' => 'success', 't' => 'تم', 'm' => 'IMAGE UPLOADED successfully','b' => true));
                        
                    }
                
                 }
            
        }
    
    
    }
    
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){
      
        if(!isset($_SESSION['_token']) OR !isset($_POST['token']) OR $_POST['token'] != $_SESSION['_token']){
    
        }    
    
    
        
      if(isset($_POST['name'],$_POST['des'],$_POST['description'],$_POST['price'],$_POST['accs'])){
            $name = htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']);
            $des = htmlspecialchars($_POST['des']);
        $description = htmlspecialchars($_POST['description']);
        $price = (int)$_POST['price'];
    
        if(strcmp($url,"myurl") == 0){
    
            returnJSON(array('t' =>'error', 'm' => 'upload', 'tp' => 'error', 'b' => 'موافق'));
    
        } 
            else if(empty($name) || empty($des) || empty($description) || empty($price) || !ctype_digit($_POST['price'])){
                returnJSON(array('t' =>'error', 'm' => 'check inputs', 'tp' => 'error', 'b' => 'close'));
    
            }else{
                $conn=$database->openConnection();
    
                $check=$conn->query("SELECT id FROM shops WHERE cid='{$_SESSION['memberId:wse6']}'");
                if($check->rowCount() == 0){
                    returnJSON(array('t' => 'خطأ', 'm' => 'لا يوجد لديك متجر', 'tp'=>'error','b' => 'موافق'));
                } else {
            $id = $check->fetch()['id'];
    
                    $stmtz=$conn->prepare("SELECT name FROM products WHERE name=:name AND sid=:sid");
                    $stmtz->bindParam(":name", $name);
            $stmtz->bindParam(":sid", $id);
                    $stmtz->execute();
                    if($stmtz->rowCount() == 0){
    
                        $stmt=$conn->prepare("INSERT INTO products (sid,name,des,description,price,createdTime) VALUES ({$id}, :name, :des,:description,:price,".time().")");
                        $stmt->bindParam(":name", $name);
                        $stmt->bindValue(":des", $des);
              $stmt->bindValue(":description", $description);
                        $stmt->bindValue(":price", $price);
    
                        $stmt->execute();
    
                        if($stmt->rowCount() > 0){
                $theid = $conn->lastInsertId();
                            $database->closeConnection();
                            returnJSON(array('t' => 'حسناً', 'm' => 'تم إضافة المنتج بنجاح', 'tp'=>'success','b' => 'موافق','theid'=>$theid));
                        }else{
                            $database->closeConnection();
    
                            returnJSON(array('t' => 'خطأ', 'm' => 'حدث خطاً غير متوقع حاول مجدداً لاحقاً', 'tp'=>'error','b' => 'موافق'));
                        }
                    }else{
                        returnJSON(array('t' => 'خطأ', 'm' => 'يوجد لديك منتج ب هذا الإسم بالفعل', 'tp'=>'info','b' => 'موافق'));
                    }
    
    
    
                }
    
    
      }
    }
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you tried to `var_dump();` or print in other ways in every line to check where you loose your `$url`? If you print your `$url` before `if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){` and it's still `'myurl'` then i think it's redeclared too deep in first `IF`.
You can read more about that in [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).